# Powershell remove/reorder repeated values (FT)

Tags: powershell

I'm having some trouble with repeated values

I've got this FT with this values:

```
           FileTypes O_OpenAccess U_UserAccess S_SubscriberAccess Duration    
  -        --------- ------------ ------------ ------------------ --------    
  video            3            0            3                  0 00:10:28,631
  document        13            0            0                 13 00:10:28,631
  audio           11            0            0                 11 00:10:28,631
  mp4              0            0            3                  0 03:55:10,000
  eaf              0            0            0                 12 03:55:10,000
  pdf              0            0            0                  1 03:55:10,000
  WAV              0            0            0                 11 03:55:10,000
  Total           27            0            3                 24 04:05:38,631
```

I need to remove the repeated values on Duration property, Duration just for video and audio respectively, I'm trying everything that i know, but nothing works.

```
          FileTypes O_OpenAccess U_UserAccess S_SubscriberAccess Duration    
  -        --------- ------------ ------------ ------------------ --------    
  video            3            0            3                  0 00:10:28,631
  document        13            0            0                 13 
  audio           11            0            0                 11 03:55:10,000
  mp4              0            0            3                  0 
  eaf              0            0            0                 12 
  pdf              0            0            0                  1 
  WAV              0            0            0                 11 
  Total           27            0            3                 24 04:05:38,631
```

My code:

```
$obj = @()
$List1 = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio").Name
ForEach ($item in $List1) {

    $group = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name -eq $item}).Group
    $obj += [pscustomobject]@{
        ' ' = $item; 
        'FileTypes' = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name -eq $item}).count; 
        'O_OpenAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "O_OpenAccess"}).count; 
        'U_UserAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "U_UserAccess"}).count; 
        'S_SubscriberAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "LOADING_BAY_10"}).count;
        'Duration' = $VideoTime
    }
}
$List2 = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "Format").Name
ForEach ($item in $List2) {
    $group = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "Format" | ? {$_.name -eq $item}).Group
    $obj += [pscustomobject]@{
        ' ' = $item; 
        'FileTypes' = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name -eq $item}).count; 
        'O_OpenAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "O_OpenAccess"}).count; 
        'U_UserAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "U_UserAccess"}).count; 
        'S_SubscriberAccess' = ($group | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "LOADING_BAY_10"}).count;
        'Duration' = $AudioTime
    }
}


    $List3 = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name}).Group
    $obj += [pscustomobject]@{
        ' ' = 'Total'; 
        'FileTypes' = $allMediaFiles.count; 
        'O_OpenAccess' = ($List3 | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "O_OpenAccess"}).count; 
        'U_UserAccess' = ($List3 | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "U_UserAccess"}).count; 
        'S_SubscriberAccess' = ($List3 | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "LOADING_BAY_10"}).count;
        'Duration' = $Allt
    }

 



$obj | FT
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `Select -unique` see `Select -?`

Comment: Thanks Neko, your approach works, but i still have the same problem, how is the sintax to put variable value on selected property. 'Duration' = $VideoTime | ?{$group | Select-Object -Property video -Unique}. I think my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Seems to me that you have merged the columns 'video_audio' and 'Format' into one column, which now makes the second foreach loop `$List2 = ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "Format").Name` impossible. Also, you do a lot of `Group-Object "SecurityTag"` calls, one for each property where you could have done this just once per loop and derive the properties from that single group..

Comment: Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565028/powershel-create-new-pscustomobject-from-pscustomobject-properties-count) I think you should rethink all this and try to get a clear view on what the output should finally be when converting your XML into PsObjects. Now you have too many steps in between that only make things more difficult.

Comment: Thanks Theo. U right, for now it is a lot of problems to solve.